# Get Google API Key

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api

How to get Google API Key ?

I am trying to get API key from this page `https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/credentials?utm_source=Docs_CreateAPIKey&utm_content=Docs_maps-backend&_gl=1*12h3m60*_ga*MTM0NjQ1MzA4OS4xNjg3NDI1NDc4*_ga_NRWSTWS78N*MTY5MzI4NjA2Ni4xMC4xLjE2OTMyODk4NjQuMC4wLjA.&project=tradex-396511`. But this is loading always.

Ami I doing any mistake ?

[image]

Comment: Try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=me_PAqPpzP0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard)

go to credentials then click create credentials

[image]

then click api key

[image]

if your using google maps make sure to go to library and enable the google maps api

[image]

you will also need to enable a billing account to use maps

[How to create api key](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=me_PAqPpzP0)